# axios could not support gzip when use ReactNative in android

Tags: android, react-native, gzip, fetch, axios

"axios": "^0.16.2"

"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"

"react-native": "^0.47.1"

Before send the request I set a header axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate'. I got some unknown response(actually it is JSON), and it works fine in iOS.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is DON'T ADD HEADER to axios. RN support gzip as OOTB.
here is a POC result on nginx,

1, the first line is a curl call, the response is 56987

2, the second line is a curl call with header  -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip", the response is 3629

3, the third line is a request send from App, the response size is 3641

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does OOTB mean here ?

Comment: OOTB stands for "Out of the box"